# Nodejs , wait until current request completes, then proceed (or) wait until firstfunction executes before going to second function

Tags: node.js

I use nodejs code:

```
var ret = firstfunction();  //this calls database and gets some return value
var output = secondfunction(ret); // in this function we used ret as parameter
```

Before `firstfunction()` completes , and before it gets the value "ret", the second function executes with parameter "undefined" as "ret" is not yet available resulting in an error .

How can i execute second function, only after first function completes execution.

```
var uname = "sachin";
var noqq=UserModel.find({uname:uname},function(err,user){
if(!err){
    myid=user[0]._id;  //SAVING myid here , I AM USING THIS IN THE NEX FUNCTION
    return myid;
}else { 
     return null;
    }
});
```

Below function should execute only after above one completes, that is after getting "myid" only.

```
var ret=CollegeModel.findById(myid, function(err,colleges){
if(!err)
{
    res.send(questions);
}
else {
    res.send(err);
}
});
```

Please show me answer implementing my code. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Node, you have to learn to do things asynchronously. You can use its many synchronous methods, but you lose out on the benefits of going fully non-blocking.

So without knowing what's in `firstfunction`, you probably have an asynchronous method in there. If so, `firstfunction` is returning before the asynchronous method is returned (internally, it's probably not even been invoked). What you need to do is send your `secondfunction` into `firstfunction()`. The simplest way to do that is to pass `secondfunction` as an argument to `firstfunction`. Your code will look something like this:

```
var firstfunction = function(myCallback) {
    var dbSuccessCallback = function(returedData) {
        // the asynchronous call has retured successfully with data

        myCallback(returnedData); 
    };
    callDatabase("SELECT a FROM b", dbSuccessCallback);
}


firstfunction(secondfunction);
```

If you do event binding in HTML, you're already probably very used to doing this:

```
mydiv.addEventListener('click',function(){/* Do something */}, true);
```

or another way:

```
var myCallback = function(){
    /* Do something */
};
mydiv.addEventListener('click',myCallback, true);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , i have marked it as useful . Please implement that using my code, i have added it now .

Answer (score 0):

Look into the node-async library for some nice wrappers around common patterns for things like this: https://github.com/caolan/async

It sounds like either series or waterfall would work well for your use case.